# Repeat index of items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem whit index 
I have a list look like this:

```
['Persian', 'League', 'is', 'the', 'largest', 'sport', 'event', 'dedicated', 
'to', 'the', 'deprived', 'areas', 'of', 'Iran', 'Persian', 'League', 
'promotes', 'peace', 'and', 'friendship', 'video', 'was', 'captured', 'by', 
'one', 'of', 'our', 'heroes', 'who', 'wishes', 'peace']
```

and i want print index of capitalize name whit capitalize name look like this:

```
0:Persian
1:League
13:Iran
14:Persian
15:League
```

but i can't and print reapet index like below:

```
0:Persian 
1:League
13:Iran
0:Persian   <=======
1:League    <=======
```

please help me guys!

Comment: Please show the code of what you tried so far.

Comment: Related: [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](//stackoverflow.com/q/522563)

Comment: `[k for k, elt in enumerate(L) if elt.capitalize() == elt]`

Comment: Where's your code ?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use a list comprehension for that:

```
[(i, word) for i, word in enumerate(l) if word.istitle()]
>> [(0, 'Persian'), (1, 'League'), (13, 'Iran'), (14, 'Persian'), (15, 'League')]
```

The function `istitle()` check if the first letter of the word start with an uppercase.

Or you can use:

```
for i, word in enumerate(l):
    if word.istitle():
        print(i,': ', word)

0 :  Persian
1 :  League
13 :  Iran
14 :  Persian
15 :  League
```

Comment: thank you very much Mohit Motwani my problem solved

Comment: @AliRahimpoor Happy to help :) Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

Shortest comprehension that returns formatted strings:

```
["{}:{}".format(*x) for x in enumerate(lst) if x[1].istitle()]
```

Comment: An elegant solution even though it is not a "code golf" contest for shortest code to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is because list `index()` returns index of first occurance in list. So, no matter how many '`Persian'`s are there in the list, only the first `'Persian'`'s index is fetched.

Use `enumerate` to iterate over list keeping track of indices and I would suggest a dictionary creation so you could use it further on:

```
lst = ['Persian', 'League', 'is', 'the', 'largest', 'sport', 'event', 'dedicated', 'to', 'the', 'deprived', 'areas', 'of', 'Iran', 'Persian', 'League', 'promotes', 'peace', 'and', 'friendship', 'video', 'was', 'captured', 'by', 'one', 'of', 'our', 'heroes', 'who', 'wishes', 'peace']

output = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x.istitle()}
# {0: 'Persian', 1: 'League', 13: 'Iran', 14: 'Persian', 15: 'League'}
```